# gactions test fails with "Your app must have at least one action for locale en"

Tags: actions-on-google, api-ai

When I run `gactions test` for one of my Actions SDK projects I get the following message:

```
     ERROR: Failed to test the app for the Assistant
     ERROR: Request contains an invalid argument.
     Field Violations:
     #  Field                         Description
     1  agent_version_content.action  Your app must have at least one action for locale en
     2017/10/09 17:48:46 Server did not return HTTP 200
```

This has also been raised at [least](https://plus.google.com/107479336164961586803/posts/Ge2RCZGgxhV) [twice](https://plus.google.com/114649172755835179936/posts/5C26Ecu2mLR) in the Google+ community - so far without any proper answer.

What can we do, to get rid of this problem? What is the cause of it?

If I create an empty project in the Console for Actions on Google and upload and test the project with this new project-id I do **not** get this message.

Another interesting hint: All information for this project (apart from it being there) in the Console was lost. I had to reenter all the stuff like app icon and so forth.

And all the time the Console pretends that I didn't upload anything. The first step of the five-step wizard has no check mark but simply says "1" and the button "Add Actions" is highlighted. but the `gactions update` returns successfully. For the newly create project, though, the step one has a checkmark.

**Edit (Oct, 10th - 16:10 UTC):**
Now I get an error message when trying to use `gactions update`:

```
     ERROR: Failed to update the app for the Assistant
     ERROR: Precondition check failed.
     Violations:
     #  Description
     1  Draft already uses en as a language so it cannot be used again for localization.
     2017/10/10 18:11:55 Server did not return HTTP 200
```

This happens - no matter if I use `action.en.json` (including `"locale": "en"` in the file) or `action.json` as filename (and not including the `locale` information in the file).

Same result with `gactions test`.

Comment: Thanks for reporting. We are looking into the issue.

Comment: We have found a bug that explains the errors you are seeing. We are working on a fix and hope to push it out soon.

Comment: The issue should be resolved now. Please try again.

Comment: Alas it's not. I amend the question with the new error message (which I only get for one of my two Actions-Console ids).