# How can I delete support for a language from the Actions on Google console?

Tags: multilingual, actions-on-google

or, more specifically, I have added information for a second language on the console, but now I cannot use "gactions test..." to deploy it because I get the error:

```
Pushing the app for the Assistant for testing...
ERROR: Failed to test the app for the Assistant
ERROR: Request contains an invalid argument.
Field Violations:
#  Field                         Description
1  agent_version_content.action  Your app must have at least one action for locale fr
2017/10/11 18:11:04 Server did not return HTTP 200
```

Consequently I must either

- Add the locale info, or
- Delete the language from the console

Neither of which I can do because

- The actions package doc does not indicate how to specify a locale for an action, and
- The console doesn't seem to provide for language deletion

Please somebody help here. Thanks

Comment: Possibly associated with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46650524/gactions-test-fails-with-your-app-must-have-at-least-one-action-for-locale-en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Information about adding the locale info is at https://developers.google.com/actions/localization/action-packages

They're still updating the documentation for the `gactions` command and the action package format itself but, in short, you need to do two things:

First, create an action package for each locale. They suggest names like "action.fr.json" and "action.en.json". The first parameter in the json for each will be:

```
"locale": "en"
```

(or "fr" or whatever locale)

Then, specify multiple action files using multiple `--action_package` parameters:

```
./gactions update --project my-project-id --action_package action.de.json --action_package action.en.json --action_package action.fr.json --action_package action.ja.json --action_package action.ko.json
```

Comment: Great - and, in the process, I found that if you return English text in the French locale, my Google Home speaks it correctly - but in a WONDERFULLY over-the-top stereotypical French accent!!! Gonna be using THAT for our French demos!

Comment: Well this does not really answer the question. I would like to delete a language on actions on google console